# Access Windows IoT Device Portal without port forwarding or UPnP

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I have many IoT clients that will soon be in the field. I want some way to have full access to the Device Portal currently on port 8080 without it being publicly exposed.

My thoughts are to develop a management server that accepts connections from multiple clients with keep alive. The connection from the IoT could be net sockets but that is open for feedback.

The management server would show the connection status of each IoT device. It would have the functionality to launch a browser session with the connected IoT device. The IoT device would serve the local Device Portal:8080 through the socket to the management servers browser session. Interaction from the management servers browser session would be transmitted back through the socket and in turn interact with the Device Portal.

I have looked over information for a few days and can’t find examples of website interaction through sockets. I request your feedback on such an approach and also ask is there are any open source projects that may assist in getting to this goal.

Thank you

Comment: You can set a strong username and password to protect the Device Portal from public exposure. Note, the device portal is a developer tool and is not suggested to included in the retail or commercial image.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://openport.io. It does exactly what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

A socket is just a software representation of a TCP connection. Ports would still be required. At least 1 port anyway. If you are accessing all those devices on the same network, you can use a reverse proxy or a VPN for external access into your network and those devices. Always use an SSL cert or IPsec Tunnel for the Proxy or VPN connection. If you open up your firewall on 80 and/or 443 to your Apache web server, apache could redirect to the backed 8080 port. Alternatively, OpenVPN could be used to give you access to the entire network by just opening port 1154 and setting up the configurations. If using OpenVPN, you would still route to the device portal on 8080, as usual, using your internal IP or host name.

If all your devices are on the same network, the nice thing about using VPN to get in is that you can connect to OpenVPN on your cell phone and then connect via SSH with an app like Termius on IOS, or any other SSH capable IOS App to your IoT device, and get things done quickly; like rebooting IoT devices, setting permissions, checking logs on the go.

Lastly, if your planning to pay for Azure, you could do that, I guess ($$$)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/